# Calculating probability from cumulative frequency graph

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I have this graph cumulative frequency graph

[image]

and this problem related to this graph:

> A student is chosen at random.
>    The probability that the student estimates that the mass is greater than M grams is 0.3.
>    Find the value of M.

I thought of doing it with relative frequency formula

0.3 = M/200

M = 0.3*200

But the answer i got was far from the right answer,so how do i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\hat{M}$ be the randomly chosen student's estimation.  Then $\Bbb{P}(\hat{M} > M) = 0.3$, so $\Bbb{P}(\hat{M} \le M) = 0.7$.  Since you have $200$ students, you need to read from the horizontal line $200 \times 0.7 = 140$ and find the corresponding value of $M$ from the curve.  In this graph, it's $M = 4$.